# Как добавить каждый элемент массива в объект таким образом:

Tags: javascript, массивы, map, foreach, объекты

```
let obj = [
  {name: "Murray", age: 25},
  {name: "Andre", age: 20},
  {name: "Ali", age: 24}
]
let height = [1.87, 1.80, 1.88]

// output
let obj = [
  {name: "Murray", age: 25, height: 1.87},
  {name: "Andre", age: 20, height: 1.80},
  {name: "Ali", age: 24, height: 1.88}
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Простым циклом можно:

```
for (let el in obj) {
    obj[el]['height'] = height[el]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
let obj = [{
    name: "Murray",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: "Andre",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Ali",
    age: 24
  }
];
let height = [1.87, 1.80, 1.88];

for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  obj[i].height = height[i];
}


console.log(obj);
```

```js
let obj = [{
    name: "Murray",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: "Andre",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Ali",
    age: 24
  }
];
let height = [1.87, 1.80, 1.88];

obj = obj.map((item, index) => ({ ...item,
  height: height[index]
}));

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
obj.forEach(function(item, i){
  item.height = height[i];
});
```